# Chi-Sq test result difference when done Manually and by SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to perform a chi-square test on my data using SAS University Edition.
Here is the strucure of my data

```
+----------+------------+------------------+-------------------+
| study_id | Control_id | study_mortality  | control_mortality |
+----------+------------+------------------|-------------------+
|       1  |         50 |       Alive      |          Alive    |
|       1  |         52 |       Alive      |          Alive    | 
|       2  |         65 |       Dead       |          Dead     |
|       2  |         70 |       Dead       |          Alive    | 
+----------+------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

I am getting different results when I do the test with SAS Vs when I do it manually using an online calculator. I used the values from 'PROC FREQ' to calculate the Chi-Sq using online calculator. Here are the outputs of frequencies and the Chi-sq test. Can someone point where the issue is.

```
proc freq data = mydata; 
tables study_mortality control_mortality;
where type=1;
run;
+-----------------+-------------------+
| study_mortality | Frequency         |           
+-----------------+-------------------
| Alive           | 7614              | 
| Dead            | 324               |   
+-----------------+-------------------+

+----------------- +-------------------+
| control_mortality| Frequency         |           
+----------------- +-------------------
| Alive            | 6922              | 
| Dead             | 159               |   
+----------------- +-------------------+

proc freq data = mydata;
tables study_mortality*control_mortality/ CHISQ;
where type=1;
run;

+-----------------+-------------------+---------+-------+
|                 | Control_mortality |         |       |
+-----------------+-------------------+---------+-------+
| Study_mortality | Alive             | Dead    | Total |
| Alive           | 5515              | 134     | 5649  |
| Dead            | 249               | 5       | 254   |
| Total           | 5764              | 139     | 5903  |
+-----------------+-------------------+---------+-------+

Statistic                   DF  Value   Prob
Chi-Square                  1   0.1722  0.6782
Likelihood Ratio Chi-Square 1   0.1818  0.6699
Continuity Adj. Chi-Square  1   0.0414  0.8388
Mantel-Haenszel Chi-Square  1   0.1722  0.6782
Phi Coefficient                -0.0054   
Contingency Coefficient         0.0054   
Cramer's V                     -0.0054
```

Comment: How do those results differ from what you get with online calculator.  First I would check the cell counts, to make sure you don't have a typo.  You should be able to  compute the chi-square stat by hand (or with a fairly simple Excel sheet).

Answer (score 0):

You have missing data. Look at the N's on those tables.

Study Mortality is around 8000 and Control Mortality is around 7000 but when you cross them you only have 5903 records. This means that certain records are excluded. There should be a line in the output saying N missing somewhere. Not sure if SAS didn't put it there or you only pasted selected output. The P value matches exactly when I use an online calculator and also match your output.

```
data have;
infile cards;
input Study Control N;
cards;
1 1 5515
1 0 134
0 1 249
0 0 5
;
run;

proc freq data=have;
table study*control / chisq;
weight N;
run;
```